# return a float value from ReadProcessMemory in python

Tags: python, winapi, reverse-engineering

I have an address containing the y-position in the game called Assault Cube (I'm learning about reverse engineering)

My problem is readprocessmemory's ReadBuffer.value returns an integer, and I'm looking for a way to receive the value as a float. Does anyone know how to do this in python?

In the picture I've tried to illustrate how an integer (1125777408) is returned, which itself is correct, but I'd like to find a way to have the float value returned (104).

[image]

```
def ReadProcessMemory(self, hProcess, lpBaseAddress):
    try:
        lpBaseAddress = lpBaseAddress
        ReadBuffer = ctypes.c_uint()
        lpBuffer = ctypes.byref(ReadBuffer)
        nSize = ctypes.sizeof(ReadBuffer)
        lpNumberOfBytesRead = ctypes.c_ulong(0)

        ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory(
                                                hProcess,
                                                lpBaseAddress,
                                                lpBuffer,
                                                nSize,
                                                lpNumberOfBytesRead
                                                )
        return ReadBuffer.value
    except (BufferError, ValueError, TypeError):
        self.CloseHandle(hProcess)
        e = 'Handle Closed, Error', hProcess, self.GetLastError()
        return e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `ctypes` method called `c_float`, so use `ctypes.c_float()` instead of `ctypes.c_int()`.

Comment: Wow that was easy - that did the trick! Thought I already tried that..

Thanks! :-)

Comment: @jubibanna: If his answer fixed your problem, please accept it as this is customary on SO.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. I was trying to accept your answer too fast and there was a 5 minute limitation. Corrected :)